# Neural network overfitting from more samples

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, natural-language, overfitting

I am fitting a neural network model for a text classification task, the issue is that as I introduce more samples from the dataset I start to see more overfitting.

[image]

This charts show train/val accuracy scores (same occurs with other metrics), the two train runs you can see improving, but the two validation runs differ, in the validation run which shows less overfitting I am giving the model the same small sample from the dataset around 3200 examples, which I repeat on each epoch, in the run which shows more severe overfitting, I am giving the model new samples each epoch.

So to summarise, when showing the model more of the full dataset the overfitting becomes worse, which is the opposite of what I would expect. My question would be; under which conditions would this occur, and what would be some methods to alleviate this issue?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Just adding some information from the discussion in the comments:

- the classes are imbalanced (80/20), but I am sampling them to ensure an even split.
- This is happening with all metrics; BCE, Recall, AUC...

Comment: How balanced is the label?  Is the subset a random sample?

Comment: The true underlying distribution is not balanced around 80/20 but I am sampling to ensure they are 50/50.

Comment: Sampling both the full set and the subset, or just the subset?

Comment: Sampling is occurring in both scenarios.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you might be more-accurately predicting the dominant class.  Perhaps track something better-calibrated than accuracy, such as RMSE or entropy, and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: I am tracking a bunch of metrics (recall, precision, loss (entropy)) but they all behave this exact same way.

Comment: @generic_user any other ideas :)